# How to set window.location on localhost including a hash mark under IE 8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I've got a bookmarklet which is meant to change the current URL.  The code is:

javascript:location.href = 'http://localhost:8888/#nominate'

However, under IE8 this ends up sending the browser to: http://localhost:8888/

How do I send IE8 to that hashmark location?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things to try:

```
window.location = 'http://localhost:8888/#nominate';
window.location.assign('http://localhost:8888/#nominate');
```

The spec also allows you to set the window.location.hash value directly, but you shouldn't have to do that.